# Customizing project and app templates in django

Tags: django

I would like to customize the files and folders created when running

```
python manage.py startapp appname
```

I find doing some things over and over again and I think it would be neat, if my customizations are present when I create a new app.

Do you know where I can customize the default files when an app is created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The files are in `django/conf/app_template` and `django/conf/project_template` for the app and project files respectively.

I don't think there is a ways to override this location without either creating your own `startapp` / `startproject` command or without modifying `django/core/management/base.py`.

Comment: ahhh, I looked at a bunch of templates in django but didn't check conf. Thanks.

Comment: I think this answer is now out of date, as there is a --template flag with which you can specify a project or app template.  See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startapp-appname-destination

Answer (score 15):

`startapp` and `startproject` accept a `--template` flag with which you can specify a directory or compressed file that the command should use as a template for you new app or project.  It also passes in a context with your app/project name that you can insert into your templates with template tags.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startapp-appname-destination for the details.

It looks like this was added in 1.4.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy your customized files instead of using the created ones without problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an older version of django, you can write your custom django-admin command, as illustrated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands).
you could write modification of startapp, which creates your custom files.