# Customised settings files using django-admin.py startproject?

Tags: django, django-settings

Whenever you run the command `django-admin.py startproject`, django automatically loads up a default settings file.

Is it possible to enhance the way this works so that it loads up your customized settings so you don't have to go in and change most of the defaults?
For example things like time zones etc. Just to make the whole process quicker.

Comment: This is a similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544085/customizing-project-and-app-templates-in-django, and I think, like the other question, the answer to this question is now out of date since the --template flag was introduced in 1.4.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startapp-appname-destination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the project template files in your Django install. In the directory where Django is installed, go to `django/conf/project_template/`. Here, you can modify the settings.py file used when you create a new project.

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but I don't really want to have to edit the django source code.

Comment: @Humphrey If you don't want to edit the django source files (which in my opinion isn't all that bad) you can always create a wrapper around `django-admin.py startproject` and write a script to personalize each project. We do something like this at my workplace that will setup our repository and write in our custom settings.

Comment: Hello @Bob, do you have a sample of creating a wrapper around Django-admin.py startproject

Answer (score 1):

You can don't use `django-admin.py startproject` commant at all. Just create your own project template with your own settings and structure, copy-paste it every time for each new site.

But don't forget about `SECRET_KEY`, it should be unique for each project.

Comment: It is absolutely not necessary to manually copy/paste the template. Spend 5 minutes to make it work with the django admin command startproject.

Answer (score 1):

you can fork and customize the django-startproject https://github.com/lincolnloop/django-startproject